# Group Values of map with same prefix entry key

Tags: java, java-8

I have hash map which contains strings like a.01, a.02, b.01, b.02 and a list as value.

Now I would like to create a new map and put there as a key the prefix of the keys (like a, b,.. etc) and as value the content of the lists of the elements with similar prefix.

```
Example: group lists of prefix a and b 
input: Map<String, List> input = {(a.1,l1), (a.2,l2),(b.1,l3), (b.2,l4)}
Output: Map<String, List> output = {(a,{l1,l2}), (b,{l3,l4})}
```

I tried the following but it is not working

```
public static Set<String> prefixName(final Map<String, List> names, final String prefix) {
        return names.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith(prefix)).map(entry -> prefix);
    }
```

Comment: i don't it is `{(a.1,l1), (a.2,l2),(b.1,l3), (b.2,l4)}` in format of `Map<String, List>`

Comment: Using streams, specifically?

Comment: If `l1` is a list, shouldn't the result be a List of List? Or do you want to combine the lists with the same prefix?

Comment: Also, what type of list is it? I hope you're not using a raw `List`.

Comment: When you want to create a map, you have to *collect* into a map. This has nothing to do with the `map` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it stream-wise you can use a mapping function as part of a collection operation. This will enable a multimap to be created with your simplified and reduced key, with the original values of that key (type `List<string>`) collected into an enclosing `List<List<String>>`:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Grouping {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<String> l1 = List.of("foo", "bar");
            List<String> l2 = List.of("goo", "car");
            List<String> l3 = List.of("boo", "par");
            List<String> l4 = List.of("loo", "tar");

            Map<String, List<String>> mapped = Map.of(
                    "a.1", l1,
                    "a.2", l2,
                    "b.1", l3,
                    "b.2", l4);

            Map<String, List<List<String>>> grouped = mapped.entrySet().
                stream().
                collect(groupingBy(e ->e.getKey().substring(0, 1), mapping(e ->e.getValue(), toList())));
            System.out.println(grouped);
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output being:

```
{a=[[foo, bar], [goo, car]], b=[[boo, par], [loo, tar]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this imperative approach:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> originalMap = new HashMap<>();
        originalMap.put("a.1",Arrays.asList("l1"));
        originalMap.put("a.2",Arrays.asList("l2"));
        originalMap.put("b.1",Arrays.asList("l3"));
        originalMap.put("b.2",Arrays.asList("l4"));

        Map<String,List<String>> newMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry: originalMap.entrySet()){
            String newKey = entry.getKey().split("\\.")[0];
            if(!newMap.containsKey(newKey)){
                newMap.put(newKey,new ArrayList<>());
            }
            newMap.get(newKey).addAll(entry.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println(newMap);
    }
```

Result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

If this task does not require *streams*, you can use the following.

Traverse the original map, checking if the new map contains the *prefix* key.
Then, either add the list to the new map list, or create a new map entry.

```java
Map<String, List<List>> parse(Map<String, List> mapA) {
    Map<String, List<List>> mapB = new HashMap<>();
    String prefix;
    List<List> lists;
    for (Map.Entry<String, List> entry : mapA.entrySet()) {
        prefix = prefix(entry.getKey());
        if (mapB.containsKey(prefix))
            mapB.get(prefix).add(entry.getValue());
        else {
            lists = new ArrayList<>();
            lists.add(entry.getValue());
            mapB.put(prefix, lists);
        }
    }
    return mapB;
}
```

Additionally, I created a method here, to substring the *prefix* from the *key*.
In which, I presume may be more complicated than a single substring.

```java
String prefix(String string) {
    /* a.01, a.02, b.01, etc. */
    return string.substring(0, string.indexOf('.'));
}
```

Here is an example of an input and output.

```java
Map<String, List> mapA = new HashMap<>();
mapA.put("a.01", List.of(1, 2, 3, 4));
mapA.put("a.02", List.of(5, 6, 7, 8));
mapA.put("b.01", List.of(9, 0, 1, 2));
mapA.put("b.02", List.of(3, 4, 5, 6));

Map<String, List<List>> mapB = parse(mapA);
System.out.println(mapB);
```

```
{a=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], b=[[9, 0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]]}
```